# Unable to Deserialize JSON into Dictionary

Tags: c#, json

I'm making an API call that returns JSON (into a variable called `jsonString`). Doing a `Console.WriteLine(jsonString)` on the JSON data reveals this:

> {"contentType":null,"serializerSettings":null,"statusCode":null,"value":"{\"contentType\":null,\"serializerSettings\":null,\"statusCode\":null,\"value\":{\"10\":\"ALABAMA\",\"11\":\"ALASKA\",\"12\":\"ARIZONA\",\"13\":\"ARKANSAS\",\"14\":\"CALIFORNIA\",\"15\":\"COLORADO\",\"16\":\"CONNECTICUT\",\"17\":\"DELAWARE\",\"18\":\"FLORIDA\",\"19\":\"GEORGIA\",\"20\":\"HAWAII\",\"21\":\"IDAHO\",\"22\":\"ILLINOIS\",\"23\":\"INDIANA\",\"24\":\"IOWA\",\"25\":\"KANSAS\",\"26\":\"KENTUCKY\",\"27\":\"LOUISIANA\",\"28\":\"MAINE\",\"29\":\"MARYLAND\",\"30\":\"MASSACHUSETTS\",\"31\":\"MICHIGAN\",\"32\":\"MINNESOTA\",\"33\":\"MISSISSIPPI\",\"34\":\"MISSOURI\",\"35\":\"MONTANA\",\"36\":\"NEBRASKA\",\"37\":\"NEVADA\",\"38\":\"NEW HAMPSHIRE\",\"39\":\"NEW JERSEY\",\"40\":\"NEW MEXICO\",\"41\":\"NEW YORK\",\"42\":\"NORTH CAROLINA\",\"43\":\"NORTH DAKOTA\",\"44\":\"OHIO\",\"45\":\"OKLAHOMA\",\"46\":\"OREGON\",\"47\":\"PENNSYLVANIA\",\"48\":\"RHODE ISLAND\",\"49\":\"SOUTH CAROLINA\",\"50\":\"SOUTH DAKOTA\",\"51\":\"TENNESSEE\",\"52\":\"TEXAS\",\"53\":\"UTAH\",\"54\":\"VERMONT\",\"55\":\"VIRGINIA\",\"56\":\"WASHINGTON\",\"57\":\"WEST VIRGINIA\",\"58\":\"WISCONSIN\",\"59\":\"WYOMING\"}}"}

I'm attempting to deserialize it into a class that looks like this:

```
public class LookupValuesResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public Dictionary<int, string> LookupValues;

    [JsonProperty("statusCode")]
    public string Status;

}
```

I've tried this:

```
LookupValuesResponse lookupresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LookupValuesResponse>(jsonString);
```

However, I get an error that the JSON cannot be deserialized:

> System.ArgumentException : Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.String].

Comment: Where is `invalidData` in the JSON?

Comment: I've just tried it, without the `invalidData` and `ErrorDesc` and it worked.

Comment: If it works without `invalidData`, then it might be the cause. Can you show us the `InvalidData` type? And are you obfuscating something from the JSON?

Comment: I dropped invalidData and ErrorDesc and no change. Do I need to add `contentType` and `serializerSettings` as well? Do I need to make it a `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: @NickHeidke Yeah. Change it to `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Comment: The JSON you have provided deserializes without problems. However, the error message that you provide seems to indicate that the JSON that has a problem is different. The value of `statusCode` is a string in the JSON according to the error message and not an object that can be converted to a dictionary.

Comment: I've copied and pasted in the raw string data, rather than the cleaned up JSON. I think I've got a problem with escape characters, not sure how to resolve it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change how the called API was returning its results. Previously I had:

```
return Ok(Json(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result));
```

instead I needed:

```
return Ok(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result));
```

Comment: Glad you solved it. BTW, you should really make use of `async` and `await`.